# the_post_navigation in single page with multiple taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pagination

I am creating a custom content that can belong to several categories: status, age and specie.
For now there are only the following terms for these taxonomies:

- species: dogs, cats
- age: adult, young, old
- status: in adoption

When viewing the “single” page and using “the_post_navigation” function to show the links to the next and previous elements, I see that it can be passed as arguments “in_same_term” and ‘taxonomy’ so that it only shows those of the same term.
This helps me to display, for example, a dog and the links to the next and previous dogs, but how can I show, for example, an adult dog that the links to the next and previous adult dog are shown? Or only adult cats? am I misusing taxonomies?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It should be possible with the filters used by `get_adjacent_post()` — https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_adjacent_post/ — but you'd have to write some custom SQL to filter what you want. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you @NabhaCosley , very cool solution. Anyway, since I'm new, do you think the taxonomies are well done? I am afraid that my searches or URLs will be complicated because I do not define them well

Comment: They look good to me! It seems like you understand the organizing principle behind taxonomies.

Comment: Now that I've looked into it more, a couple of custom WP_Query calls using `tax_query` are probably going to be easier. You could think about that as well.

Comment: Thanks @NabhaCosley .With the "get_{type}_post_where" filters I can override "get_adjacent_post", but because the ids of the terms need to be retrieved and the query is a string, I think it is more cumbersome.
I'm reading what you say about "tax_query" and it looks great, but I don't know how to use it yet. I'm using a child theme of Astra, which renders the navigation like this:
the_post_navigation(
apply_filters(
'astra_single_post_navigation',
[...]
that's why it's easier for me to use "get_adjacent_post", but also slower and more expensive. how can i use WP_Query? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NabhaCosley The orthodox way would be to replace the function that render the links in the parent theme and include that query and its layout in my child theme?

Comment: With WP_Query you’d end up writing a replacement for the_post_navigation(), basically. Since your parent theme is Astra, you would only make changes to your child theme, which is where you’d put that function (and call it).